# Probability of begin the first of two players to get H when tossing a coin

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Two players, $A$ and $B$, alternately and independently flip a coin and the first player to obtain a $H$ wins. Assume player $A$ flips first. Suppose that $P(H)=p$. Show that for all $p$, $0<p<1$, $P(A \ \text{wins}) > 1/2$.

I know it should involve using the geometric series, i.e.
$P(A \ \text{wins})=\dfrac{p}{1-(1-p)^2}$

Comment: You should edit the title to be more descriptive of the question. Also, how did you get $P(A \ \text{wins}) = \frac{p}{1-(1-p)^2}$? I believe that is indeed the correct answer, although it can be simplified.

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/931779/15941) to a question about _three_ players and see if you can modify it for use in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we continue flipping the coin after someone wins.  This does not affect the probability of either player winning.

So the first two flips are $HH, HT, TH, TT$.  On the result of two tails, we repeat the process.  So the probability of A ultimately winning is recursively measured by: $$
\begin{align}
\mathsf P(A) & = p + (1-p)^2\mathsf P(A) \\[2ex] \therefore \mathsf P(A) & = \frac p {1-(1-p)^2} & \text{iff }p\neq 0
\\ & = \frac 1 {2-p}
\\[3ex]
\forall p\in(0, 1) &: \frac 1 {2-p}\in (\frac 1 2, 1)
\\[2ex]
\therefore \mathsf P(A) & > \frac 1 2 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\begin{align}
P(\text{A wins})&=p+(1-p)
\cdot P(\text{B wins an identical game playing first})\\
&=p+(1-p)\cdot (1-P(\text{A wins)})\\
&=p+(1-p) -(1-p)\cdot P(A\text { wins})\\
&=1-(1-p)\cdot P(A\text { wins})\\
\end{align}
$

Thus

$$(2-p)\cdot P(\text{A wins})=1\text{, whence }P(\text{A wins})={\frac{1}{2-p}}> \frac{1}{2}$$